# .net mvc working on a different computer getting compile errors due to assemblies missing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on a small personal project playing with the .net framework. I put my code on github so I could easily transfer it between my home pc and my laptop. I was getting The type or namespace "" dosnt exist (are you missing an assembly reference) when using the cloned project. This was even after all the packages were restored via nuget.

Today I tried just copying the entire project and the package folder to a usb stick and then running the project. EDIT: This actually works but dosnt explain why my cloned project isnt finding the assemblies, as I would much prefer to use github to keep my project up to date.

IE: here is what my web.config has for Entity Framework

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Im not sure what else to do.

Comment: What kind of files are missing?

Comment: None of the files are missing, the .dll's are all in the packages folder but im still getting errors like:The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have the MVC nuget package installed?

Comment: jrummel, correct it is installed when viewed through Nuget.

Comment: Are any of the project references missing in Visual Studio Solution Explorer when you open the cloned project? It is likely the second pc that you are opening the project on doesn't have the same components installed as the original pc.

Comment: Under my References some of them have a yellow triangle and give an error when trying to view. However the .dlls are present in my packages folder after restoring with nuget.